# Nginx docker container serve same static files under different location

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, containers

I am serving static files using Nginx docker container. I have mounted the directory to be served. I want to serve the same directory under a different location. Consider the use case of serving yum mirrors. The packages in 7.3.1611 should be served under 7.3 as well.

Initially, I tried creating symlinks, linking 7.3.1611 to 7.3 but since docker containers don't handle the symlinks, Nginx didn't serve the linked directories.
The second thing I am trying is to serve the same directories under different location in Nginx. But that too doesn't work, I get 404.

Here is the sample nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name _;

    # Enable symlinks for follow up
    disable_symlinks off;

    location /yum/7.3 {
        alias /opt/mirror/yum/7.3;

        auth_basic            "Yum Repository";

        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        autoindex on;   #enable listing of directory index
    }

    location /yum {
        root /opt/mirror;

        auth_basic            "Yum Repository";

        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        autoindex on;   #enable listing of directory index
    }

    location / {
      return 412;
    }
}
```

docker-compose.yml looks like this

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    # command: "/bin/bash -c exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "/home/admin/nginx_root.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"
      - "/tmp/mirror:/opt/mirror/yum"
    ports:
      - 25000:80
```

```
$ ls -l /tmp/mirror
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jul  4 06:51 7.3.1611
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul  4 06:52 7.4.1804
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul  4 06:52 7.5.1804
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jul  4 07:07 7.6.1810
```

This works fine when I access http://localhost:25000/yum/7.3.1611/. 
But http://localhost:25000/yum/7.3/ gives 404.

Now, when I mount explicitly **/tmp/mirror/7.3.1611:/opt/mirror/yum/7.3** then 
this http://localhost:25000/yum/7.3/ works fine. But I don't want to keep
mounting every such directory.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanking in advance.

Comment: `but since docker containers don't handle the symlinks, that didn't work` What?

Comment: If you create the symlink on the host `ln -s 7.3.16.11 7.3`, what happens?  Beyond not following symlinks on its own they generally work just fine in Docker.

Comment: the symlinks doesn't get mount as a directory. When I enter into the container. I cannot `cd` into the symlinked directory.